# how to get fields from a pojo dynamically

Tags: java, variables, field, pojo

Below is my `POJO` class which has 50 fields with setters and getters.

```
Class Employee{
int m1;
int m2;
int m3;
.
.
int m50;
//setters and getters
```

From my another class I need to get all these 50 fields to get their sum

```
Employee e1 =new Emploee();
int total = e1.getM1()+e2.getM2()+........e2.getM50();
```

Instead of doing this manually for 50 records is there any way to do it dynamically(by any loop).

Thanks

Comment: Just curious -- why on earth would you have a 1000 fields instead of a List?

Comment: You may use java reflection

Comment: I think reflection is far beyond the scope of this example.

Comment: Why on earth do you even have 1000 fields in a single class? Are all of those bits of data really so interconnected they belong together?

Comment: not 1000 exactly, just for an idea I gave that number. is there any way to do it if it has 10 fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use java reflection. For simplicity I assume your `Employee` calss only contains `int` field. But you can use the similar rules used here for getting `float`, `double` or `long` value.  Here is a complete code -

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

class Employee{

    private int m=10;
    private int n=20;
    private int o=25;
    private int p=30;
    private int q=40;
}

public class EmployeeTest{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException{

        int sum = 0;
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Field[] allFields = employee.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field each : allFields) {

            if(each.getType().toString().equals("int")){

                Field field = employee.getClass().getDeclaredField(each.getName());
                field.setAccessible(true);

                Object value = field.get(employee);
                Integer i = (Integer) value;
                sum = sum+i;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Sum :" +sum);
 }

}
```

Comment: I think that he doesn't know how to use an array, and reflection is definitely now what we want him to learn in place of arrays or lists.

Answer (score 4):

I can't possibly imagine a real life scenario where you'd have 1000 fields in a class. Having said that, you can invoke all your getters reflectively. Use **[Introspector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)** to accomplish this task:

```
int getEmployeeSum(Employee employee)
{    
    int sum = 0;
    for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(Employee.class).getPropertyDescriptors())
    {
        sum += propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(employee);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dont use 1000 fields! use an array with 1000 elements, then fill `array[i-1]` with `mi` your class would be something like:

```
Class Employee{
    int[] empArr = new int[1000];
}
```

then use could find sum like this:

```
int sum = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<1000 ; i++)
    sum+= e1.empArr[i]
```

Comment: Thnk you but I am retreiving my data from data base and storing in a pojo, so I need to use my pojo class only

Comment: So you have a table with 1000 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, instead of having a separate variable for each m1, m2, m3, ... you can put them in one array like so:

```
Class Employee {
    public int[] m = new int[1000];
}

Employee e1 = new Employee();
int total = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < e1.m.length; i++) {
    total += e1.m[i];
}
```

Comment: I have only fields because I am using spring batch.